# How to refresh a folder's data in asp.net 2.0 using c#

Tags: asp.net

Again i rewrite my question with more details i.e. I am developing a website in Asp.net 2.0 in  that i'm tracking the user's some details like their id,no of page hitted and time of hitting etc, in a LogfileDate(the LogfileDate contains whole day summary of all users) saved inside a folder(Folder is inside my project). And at another day when a new logfileDate created i want to mail the previous day Logfile and delete that file after sending. Everything happened but when It is going to delete its shows file is accessed by another process. So I need to refresh that folder after sending mail so that it got free with buffer. I'm not using IIS and i dont want it to use.

Comment: How are you writing to this log file? Are you using some framework or doing it manually? If not post some sample code how do you write data to this file. For a file to be locked it means that the file handle is still open.

Comment: Try to review you code and make sure that every time when you write logs to file, you close streams and writers.

Answer (score 2):

Probably, when you wrote log data to file, file handler was not closed.